# derivation for the reflectance equation for a multilayer systems

Tags: waves, reflection

Hello everyone I was trying to derive the Reflectance equation for the multilayer systems in the equational form in terms of reflectance coefficient and phase factor. Can anyone please tell me what are the assumptions because I am very close to the answer but I haven't reached it completely.

Comment: Reflectance of what kind of waves? Sound waves? EM waves? You have not provided enough information to make the question clear.

Comment: sorry about that, it is an EM P-polarized wave, through a multilayer medium

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609275/deriving-reflection-coeffecient-for-multilayer-system

Comment: You’ve asked this question three times. A comment on a previous version pointed you to a Wikipedia article. My guess is that it has all the relevant assumptions. Your first post has not even been closed, so I do not understand the reason for your repostings. And even if it had been closed, you are not supposed to repost. You are supposed to edit and wait for the question to be reopened.

Comment: Finally, when a comment points out that something is unclear, please do not clarify by writing another comment. Instead, edit the *question*.